# Failed to publish PowerShell module to the PSGallery

Tags: powershell, module, powershellget

I've been working on my first PS module, and wanted to share the beginning of my work with the community on the PSGallery.

When running the [`Publish-Module`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/powershellget/publish-module?view=powershell-7.3), under PowerShell 7, I get the following error:

```
Publish-Module -Path "C:\Users\Douda\Projects\PSSymantecCloud\Output\PSSymantecCloud\" -NuGetApiKey $ApiKey -Verbose
```

Error:

```
Write-Error: Failed to generate the compressed file for module 'C:\Program Files\dotnet\dotnet.exe failed to pack: error MSBuild version 17.3.2+561848881 for .NET   Determining projects to restore... C:\Program
Files\dotnet\sdk\6.0.403\Sdks\Microsoft.NET.Sdk\targets\Microsoft.NET.EolTargetFrameworks.targets(28,5): warning NETSDK1138: The target framework 'netcoreapp2.0' is out of support and will not receive security updates in the future. Please refer to 
https://aka.ms/dotnet-core-support for more information about the support policy. 

[C:\Users\XXXX\AppData\Local\Temp\981e0c61-cd9d-434f-a47b-f706deca98c4\Temp.csproj] C:\Program
Files\dotnet\sdk\6.0.403\Sdks\Microsoft.NET.Sdk\targets\Microsoft.NET.EolTargetFrameworks.targets(28,5): warning NETSDK1138: The target framework 'netcoreapp2.0' is out of support and will not receive security updates in the future. Please refer to 
https://aka.ms/dotnet-core-support for more information about the support policy. [C:\Users\XXXX\AppData\Local\Temp\981e0c61-cd9d-434f-a47b-f706deca98c4\Temp.csproj]

C:\Users\XXXX\AppData\Local\Temp\981e0c61-cd9d-434f-a47b-f706deca98c4\Temp.csproj : error NU1100: Unable to resolve 'Microsoft.NETCore.App (>= 2.0.0)' for '.NETCoreApp,Version=v2.0'.   Failed to restore
C:\Users\XXXX\AppData\Local\Temp\981e0c61-cd9d-434f-a47b-f706deca98c4\Temp.csproj (in 83 ms).  '.
```

Seems like a compiling issue due to out of support .NET Framework, but I didn't install anything and would assume my default Windows 11 + PS7 isn't enough ?

What am I missing ?

Tried on PS 5.1 with a different error

```
Publish-PSArtifactUtility : Failed to publish module 'PSSymantecCloud': 'The underlying connection was closed: An unexpected error occurred on a send.
'.
At C:\Program Files\WindowsPowerShell\Modules\PowerShellGet\1.0.0.1\PSModule.psm1:1227 char:17
+                 Publish-PSArtifactUtility -PSModuleInfo $moduleInfo
+                 ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [Write-Error], WriteErrorException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : FailedToPublishTheModule,Publish-PSArtifactUtility
```

Comment: What version of .NET do you have installed? I've experienced this error before. You need to update a private function of PowerShellGet

Comment: `Update-Module PowerShellGet -RequiredVersion 2.2.5`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Had the same problem, the issue is with PowerShellGet, had to manually update their `.psm1` changing:

```xml
<TargetFramework>netcoreapp2.0</TargetFramework>
```

To `net6` (in my case):

```
<TargetFramework>net6</TargetFramework>
```

This will keep happening until they decide to fix their thing:

[image: thing]

So for the time being, this code can be used to automatically update the affected file targeting the right .NET Version (**do note I'm replacing with `net6`, use the correct version for you, likely will be `net6` but can't be sure**).

**Also note, running this code will require an elevated session, or you would get Access Denied errors**.

```
# find the file having wrong .NET version
$path = Get-ChildItem (Get-Module PowerShellGet -ListAvailable).ModuleBase -Recurse -File |
    Select-String -Pattern netcoreapp2.0 | ForEach-Object Path

# unload the module
Remove-Module PowerShellGet -Verbose -Force -EA 0

# update the file
$path | ForEach-Object {
    (Get-Content -LiteralPath $_ -Raw).Replace('netcoreapp2.0', 'net6') |
        Set-Content $_
}

Import-Module PowerShellGet -Force -Verbose

# now try to publish
```