# Can't publish script to PowerShell gallery, getting error

Tags: powershell, publish, powershell-7.3

```
Publish-Script -Path "path-to-script.ps1" -NuGetApiKey 123456789
```

after doing that, I get this error in PowerShell 7.3:

```
Write-Error: Failed to generate the compressed file for script 'C:\Program Files\dotnet\dotnet.exe failed to pack: error  '.
```

and I get this error in PowerShell 5.1:

```
Publish-PSArtifactUtility : Failed to generate the compressed file for script 'C:\Program Files\dotnet\dotnet.exe
failed to pack: error
'.
At C:\Program Files\WindowsPowerShell\Modules\PowerShellGet\2.2.5\PSModule.psm1:11338 char:17
+ ...             Publish-PSArtifactUtility @PublishPSArtifactUtility_Param ...
+                 ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [Write-Error], WriteErrorException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : FailedToCreateCompressedScript,Publish-PSArtifactUtility
```

my script has no dependency.

this problem has been going on for the past 2 weeks.

I even gave my script with API key to a friend from another country and they receive the same error too.
how can I fix this? I've published previous versions of this script before at least 6 times.

I've tried resetting my API key and running PowerShell as admin, didn't fix it.

**Update:**

I installed .NET 7 runtimes x64 and used this command [from this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74549382/20682592) on PowerShell 5.1:

```
# find the file having wrong .NET version
$path = Get-ChildItem (Get-Module PowerShellGet -ListAvailable).ModuleBase -Recurse -File |
    Select-String -Pattern netcoreapp2.0 | ForEach-Object Path

# unload the module
Remove-Module PowerShellGet -Verbose -Force -EA 0

# update the file
$path | ForEach-Object {
    (Get-Content -LiteralPath $_ -Raw).Replace('netcoreapp2.0', 'net7') |
        Set-Content $_
}

Import-Module PowerShellGet -Force -Verbose

# now try to publish
```

but still getting error:

```
Publish-PSArtifactUtility : Failed to generate the compressed file for script 'C:\Program Files\dotnet\dotnet.exe
failed to pack: error
'.
At C:\Program Files\WindowsPowerShell\Modules\PowerShellGet\2.2.5\PSModule.psm1:11338 char:17
+ ...             Publish-PSArtifactUtility @PublishPSArtifactUtility_Param ...
+                 ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [Write-Error], WriteErrorException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : FailedToCreateCompressedScript,Publish-PSArtifactUtility
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sSlqR.png)

Comment: Have a look here https://stackoverflow.com/q/74548911/15339544 I think your issue is probably related

Comment: Should I install .NET runtime?

Comment: No, see the answer, the issue is not your .NET Version. The issue is PowerShellGet team not updating their module properly.

Comment: @SantiagoSquarzon please take a look at my question, I updated it. added a screenshot of the exact part where PowerShell is complaining about in the module.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed the problem by installing .NET Core 2.0 SDK

https://dotnet.microsoft.com/en-us/download/dotnet/thank-you/sdk-2.1.202-windows-x64-installer